# having issue with sidewaystable environment

Tags: tables, rotating, sidewaystable

I am using the `sidewaystable` environment to fit a big table into one page. The template that I am using is *INFORMS Journal on Computing Style Files* provided  [here](https://pubsonline.informs.org/authorportal/latex-style-files); the document class is called `informs3`.

My table goes out of the page in a bizarre way shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clDfa.jpg).

An example table is provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224133/table-doesnt-fit-page-even-with-rotating?rq=1);

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.5pt} 
  \centering
  \caption{Total members per cantonal gymnastics organization 1888--1930}
  \scriptsize
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{20}{r} @{}}
     \hline
          & 88    & 90    & 91    & 92    & 94    & 97    & 98    & 99    & 00  & 01    & 02    & 03    & 04    & 05    & 06    & 07    & 08    & 27    & 28    & 30 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    AG    & 1393 & 1514 & 1566 & 1569 & 1627 & 2011 & 1963 & 2080 & 2408 & 2526 & 2520 & 2635 & 2907 & 3087 & 3450 & 3845 & 4081 & 11503 & 11704 & 12043 \bigstrut[t]\\
    AP    & 474   & 458   & 517   & 611   & 581   & 740   & 781   & 876   & 908   & 1035 & 1073 & 1065 & 1134 & 1160 & 1323 & 1452 & 1573 & 2262 & 2420 & 2316 \\
    BL    & 587   & 648   & 674   & 868   & 1020 & 1258 & 1379 & 1498 & 1423 & 1466 & 1562 & 1688 & 1821 & 1781 & 1824 & 2031 & 2106 & 4964 & 5104 & 5284 \\
    BS    & 629   & 872   & 1246 & 1269 & 1406 & 1778 & 1928 & 2344 & 2399 & 2353 & 2388 & 2557 & 2598 & 2667 & 2526 & 2761 & 3015 & 4680 & 4750 & 4666 \\
    BE    & 2412 & 2474 & 2458 & 2543 & 2778 & 2878 & 3213 & 3264 & 4366 & 4429 & 6511 & 6516 & 5559 & 6128 & 6722 & 7767 & 8678 & 18277 & 18440 & 18296 \\
    C     & 707   & 731   & 754   & 2057 & 1045 & 1260 & 1327 & 1298 & 1350 & 1265 & 1253 & 1293 & 1426 & 1445 & 1523 & 1896 & 2086 & 1964 & 2167 & 2440 \\
    FR    & 282   & 331   & 397   & 853   & 461   & 480   & 573   & 726   & 824   & 743   & 743   & 755   & 633   & 637   & 655   & 752   & 716   & 1399 & 1390 & 1443 \\
    GE    &       &       &       & 373   & 946   & 928   & 988   & 1084 & 1143 & 1107 & 1129 & 1056 & 1653 & 1862 & 2060 & 2143 & 2160 & 3312 & 3265 & 3027 \\
    GL    & 321   & 372   & 422   & 817   & 377   & 480   & 502   & 562   & 594   & 629   & 581   & 648   & 690   & 731   & 690   & 753   & 721   & 1758 & 1837 & 1932 \\
    GR    & 411   & 552   & 546   & 467   & 563   & 657   & 660   & 698   & 734   & 883   & 954   & 1056 & 1171 & 1441 & 1460 & 1460 & 1556 & 1614 & 1717 & 1793 \\
    LU    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 4228 & 4280 & 4693 \\
    NE    &       &       &       & 566   & 1674 & 1732 & 1782 & 1988 & 1987 & 2006 & 2241 & 2328 & 2267 & 2347 & 2389 & 2658 & 2697 & 3155 & 3097 & 3222 \\
    SH    & 334   & 264   & 425   & 1752 & 566   & 645   & 698   & 735   & 723   & 744   & 937   & 1051 & 1113 & 1192 & 1203 & 1313 & 1427 & 2605 & 2623 & 2868 \\
    SO    & 551   & 791   & 862   & 493   & 780   & 871   & 1098 & 1084 & 998   & 1146 & 1061 & 1154 & 1299 & 1505 & 1666 & 1714 & 1739 & 5661 & 5761 & 6392 \\
    SG    & 1422 & 1865 & 1863 & 955   & 2179 & 2372 & 2340 & 2558 & 2740 & 2892 & 2949 & 3177 & 3441 & 3631 & 4048 & 4448 & 5083 & 9175 & 9167 & 8846 \\
    TI    &       & 392   & 392   & 795   & 402   & 414   & 381   & 386   & 386   & 384   & 619   & 486   & 519   & 402   & 452   & 454   & 450   & 1034 & 1025 & 899 \\
    TG    & 743   & 829   & 879   & 402   & 1121 & 1249 & 1360 & 1382 & 1486 & 1669 & 1745 & 1882 & 2019 & 2159 & 2284 & 2454 & 2776 & 6117 & 6057 & 6030 \\
    VD    &       &       &       & 2088 & 2394 & 2627 & 3132 & 3114 & 3028 & 2886 & 3172 & 3040 & 3343 & 3254 & 2937 & 3061 & 2992 & 7073 & 6533 & 5821 \\
    VS    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 230   & 235   & 268   & 330   & 298   & 341   & 341   & 341   & 341   & 974   & 1003 & 949 \\
    ZH    & 4144 & 5000 & 5488 & 5752 & 5576 & 7445 & 7858 & 8410 & 8807 & 9125 & 9465 & 10202 & 10491 & 11139 & 11546 & 13262 & 14358 & 28706 & 29350 & 30742 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    Total & 14410 & 17093 & 18489 & 24230 & 25496 & 29825 & 31963 & 34087 & 36534 & 37523 & 41171 & 42919 & 44382 & 46909 & 49099 & 54565 & 58555 & 120461 & 121690 & 123702 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Packages required are;

```
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{booktabs,rotating,caption}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you see the posting [Sideways table cut off](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171830/5001)?

Comment: Thanks for the sharing. I believe that should solve my problem. I will remove my post to avoid the duplication.

Comment: Don't delete this posting! It might still be useful to future users of the `informs3` document class who wish to employ a `sidewaystable` environment.

Comment: In fact, the problem is not solved. I will keep the question and will work on it little bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your table is to big that can be fit in text area. I haven't document class `informs3`, but the following suggestion should work with it too:

- for table environment is used `tabular*` and for it is prescribed width `\linewidth`
- for columns with numbers are used `S` column types
- determination of the horizontal spaces between column is left to macro `\extracolsep`
- for table rules are used rules determined in the `booktabs` package
- more vertical space between rows is done by use `makegapedcells` from the `makecell` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{bigstrut} % not used
\usepackage{rotating,caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, rotating, siunitx} % <---
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % not used
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}  
%    \vspace*{20\baselineskip}  % it might help at "informs3" document class
\setcellgapes{2pt}     % <--- new
\makegapedcells        % <--- new
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}     % <--- changed
\sisetup{group-four-digits}   % <--- new
  \centering
  \caption{Total members per cantonal gymnastics organization 1888--1930}
  \small                      % <--- please adjust according to your page layout
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l    % <--- changed
                                *{17}{S[table-format=5.0]}   % <--- changed
                                *{ 3}{S[table-format=6.0]} } % <---- new
     \toprule  % <--- changed
        & 88    & 90    & 91    & 92    & 94    & 97    & 98    & 99    & 00    & 01    
        & 02    & 03    & 04    & 05    & 06    & 07    & 08    & 27    & 28    & 30    \\
    \midrule  % <--- changed
    AG  & 1393  & 1514  & 1566  & 1569  & 1627  & 2011  & 1963  & 2080  & 2408  & 2526 
        & 2520  & 2635  & 2907  & 3087  & 3450  & 3845  & 4081  & 11503 & 11704 & 12043 \\
    AP  & 474   & 458   & 517   & 611   & 581   & 740   & 781   & 876   & 908   & 1035 
        & 1073  & 1065  & 1134  & 1160  & 1323  & 1452  & 1573  & 2262  & 2420  & 2316  \\
    BL  & 587   & 648   & 674   & 868   & 1020  & 1258  & 1379  & 1498  & 1423  & 1466 
        & 1562  & 1688  & 1821  & 1781  & 1824  & 2031  & 2106  & 4964  & 5104  & 5284  \\
    BS  & 629   & 872   & 1246  & 1269  & 1406  & 1778  & 1928  & 2344  & 2399  & 2353 
        & 2388  & 2557  & 2598  & 2667  & 2526  & 2761  & 3015  & 4680  & 4750  & 4666 \\
    BE  & 2412  & 2474  & 2458  & 2543  & 2778  & 2878  & 3213  & 3264  & 4366  & 4429 
        & 6511  & 6516  & 5559  & 6128  & 6722  & 7767  & 8678  & 18277 & 18440 & 18296 \\
    C   & 707   & 731   & 754   & 2057  & 1045  & 1260  & 1327  & 1298  & 1350  & 1265 
        & 1253  & 1293  & 1426  & 1445  & 1523  & 1896  & 2086  & 1964  & 2167  & 2440 \\
    FR  & 282   & 331   & 397   & 853   & 461   & 480   & 573   & 726   & 824   & 743   
        & 743   & 755   & 633   & 637   & 655   & 752   & 716   & 1399  & 1390  & 1443 \\
    GE  &       &       &       & 373   & 946   & 928   & 988   & 1084  & 1143  & 1107  
        & 1129  & 1056  & 1653  & 1862  & 2060  & 2143  & 2160  & 3312  & 3265  & 3027 \\
    GL  & 321   & 372   & 422   & 817   & 377   & 480   & 502   & 562   & 594   & 629   
        & 581   & 648   & 690   & 731   & 690   & 753   & 721   & 1758  & 1837  & 1932 \\
    GR  & 411   & 552   & 546   & 467   & 563   & 657   & 660   & 698   & 734   & 883   
        & 954   & 1056  & 1171  & 1441  & 1460  & 1460  & 1556  & 1614  & 1717  & 1793 \\
    LU  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       
        &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 4228  & 4280  & 4693 \\
    NE  &       &       &       & 566   & 1674  & 1732  & 1782  & 1988  & 1987  & 2006 
        & 2241  & 2328  & 2267  & 2347  & 2389  & 2658  & 2697  & 3155  & 3097  & 3222 \\
    SH  & 334   & 264   & 425   & 1752  & 566   & 645   & 698   & 735   & 723   & 744   
        & 937   & 1051  & 1113  & 1192  & 1203  & 1313  & 1427  & 2605  & 2623  & 2868 \\
    SO  & 551   & 791   & 862   & 493   & 780   & 871   & 1098  & 1084  & 998   & 1146 
        & 1061  & 1154  & 1299  & 1505  & 1666  & 1714  & 1739  & 5661  & 5761  & 6392 \\
    SG  & 1422  & 1865  & 1863  & 955   & 2179  & 2372  & 2340  & 2558  & 2740  & 2892 
        & 2949  & 3177  & 3441  & 3631  & 4048  & 4448  & 5083  & 9175  & 9167  & 8846 \\
    TI  &       & 392   & 392   & 795   & 402   & 414   & 381   & 386   & 386   & 384   
        & 619   & 486   & 519   & 402   & 452   & 454   & 450   & 1034  & 1025  & 899 \\
    TG  & 743   & 829   & 879   & 402   & 1121  & 1249  & 1360  & 1382  & 1486  & 1669 
        & 1745  & 1882  & 2019  & 2159  & 2284  & 2454  & 2776  & 6117  & 6057  & 6030 \\
    VD  &       &       &       & 2088  & 2394  & 2627  & 3132  & 3114  & 3028  & 2886 
        & 3172  & 3040  & 3343  & 3254  & 2937  & 3061  & 2992  & 7073  & 6533  & 5821 \\
    VS  &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & 230   & 235   
        & 268   & 330   & 298   & 341   & 341   & 341   & 341   & 974   & 1003  & 949 \\
    ZH  & 4144  & 5000  & 5488  & 5752  & 5576  & 7445  & 7858  & 8410  & 8807  & 9125 
        & 9465  & 10202 & 10491 & 11139 & 11546 & 13262 & 14358 & 28706 & 29350 & 30742 \\
    \midrule
  Total & 14410 & 17093 & 18489 & 24230 & 25496 & 29825 & 31963 & 34087 & 36534 & 37523 
        & 41171 & 42919 & 44382 & 46909 & 49099 & 54565 & 58555 & 120461& 121690& 123702 \\
    \bottomrule     % <--- changed
    \end{tabular*}  % <--- changed
  \label{tab:addlabel}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it is still not working.

Comment: @ball_jan, what is not working? Did you test MWE as it is? Did you test with `informs3` document class? Can please show results of your tests and received errors?

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted your example with the packages provided in ```inform3``` document class. I do not receive any error. The table still goes off the page. Please see https://imgur.com/hVWp8UA.

Comment: @ball_jan, interestingly ... try the following (drthy hack): after `\begin{sidewaystable}` insert `\vspace*{12\baselineskip}` and see what happen.

Comment: lol. Actually, ```\vspace*{20\baselineskip}``` worked.

Comment: @ball_jan, number 12 was just a guessing with anticipation, that you will figured out which one will be appropriate ... :-)  :-)

Comment: When I replace the numbers with a string value under the ```toprule```, all the characters mix to each other and looks like this https://imgur.com/YKbC0i4. Do you know what it could be the reason? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In `S` columns text in cells had to be enclosed with curly braces.

Comment: Since I don't have enough reputation, I am not able like your comment, but thanks again. You're a life saver.